# Check part of a document with Aspell

Tags: vim, text, markdown, aspell

I do notes from books and lectures, and I usually ended up with large text files that are updating. How do I use aspell, if possible, to just check the new text I added?

let's say I added new text from line n to n+x. And I want to check just the x new lines, nothing more.

Note that my documents usually contains words, names, lastnames or acronyms that are not in the aspell database and they are not that common to put them in a blacklist.

By the way, my editor is vim.

Comment: Have you tried running spell on a diff? For that matter, what have you tried and why didn't;t that work for you? Your question is a little light on info.

Comment: My first approach was to write it somewhere else, check spell and just append it... Too much work. Then I tried to use visual block in vim and then use aspell but I didnt have success on that.  your suggestion is basically the same as my first approach.  usually I try to find one command/script solution.